# Make Skype window on a Mac smaller

Tags: macos, skype

There's a similar question out there, but it's for Windows and the answer is not applicable.  Right now, the minimum Skype window size on a Mac is about 2/5ths of my screen.  That's a lot of real estate for just one conversation; however, Skype will not allow me to make it smaller.  It's pretty irritating.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is drag the sidebar all the way to the left so it disappears. Then, the minimum size of a Skype window will be around 652×548 px.

[image]

You also can't [edit Skype's interface files](https://superuser.com/questions/302520/how-can-i-edit-the-user-interfaces-of-mac-os-x-programs/302521#302521) because Skype somehow checks the files for integrity and once you modify them, well …

```
7/12/12 4:15:55 PM  [0x0-0x578578].com.skype.skype[5252]    Check 2 failed. Can't run Skype
```