# Can I set a background image in the Textmate editor window?

Tags: macos, textmate

In TextMate I can set the background color, and background opacity, but is it possible to use an image as the background - like in iTerm2?

[image: Picture.png]

If not, are there any external programs which I could use to force this to happen - such as how [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/) will allow you to keep a window on top or adjust its transparency?

Comment: No — TextMate uses its own text editing control as far as I'm concerned. You can try playing around [with this](http://superuser.com/q/302520/48078), but I'm not sure you're going to get that far. Better to request that feature from TextMate devs.

Comment: Want to make that an answer or should I delete the question?

Comment: Feel free to let that question stick around. Who knows, maybe some day TextMate will have that feature or someone is able to hack the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by default. See [this list of hacks](http://wiki.macromates.com/Main/AlternativeGUIs) for what can be done with TextMate's UI.

This an abominable idea, by the way.

Comment: And why is it abominable?

Comment: Because it's too distracting.